# VBA How to loop until the last used cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the returns of a stock after each close date and list it in a column. My problem is that the start and end dates change and any cell that is not used for returns has to be completely cleared of contents. Here is what I have so far.

```
   Sheets("returns").Range("a2").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(returns(Imported!RC[4],Imported!R[1]C[4]),"""")"
Sheets("returns").Range("a2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("a2:a937")
Range("a2:a937").Select

 Sheets("returns").Range("c2").FormulaR1C1 = _
     "=IFERROR(returns(Imported!RC[10],Imported!R[1]C[10]),"""")"
Sheets("returns").Range("C2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("c2:c937")
Range("C2:C937").Select
```

This works for what I need but it leaves a formula in the empty cells which I can't have for the next step of my project. It also leaves a -1 return in the last row when I run out of data. The -1 return isn't too big of a deal if that can't be fixed. Is there a way to clear the contents of a cell that doesn't contain a value but contains a formula?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want in terms of input and output, please post an example of data before and after running the vba code

Comment: Can you specify the column which you are referring to work out the last filled row?

Answer (score 1):

Here’s what I think you want…

- You have data in worksheet “Imported”
- You want formulas in worksheet “returns” for the same number of rows that   exist in worksheet “Imported”

```
Sub addFormulasBasedOnRecordCount()
' ========================================================
' jdoxey
' Version 1.0
' ========================================================

Dim wsWithData As Worksheet ' the name of the worksheet that has the data
Dim wsFormulas As Worksheet ' the name of the worksheet that you want the formulas in

Set wsWithData = Worksheets("imported") ' change the "name" to be what you want
Set wsFormulas = Worksheets("returns")  ' change the "name" to be what you want

Dim activeRows As Long  ' this will be the number of rows that have data

' gets the number of rows in "wsWithData",
' assumes that the data starts in "A1"
' and there are no empty rows
activeRows = wsWithData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

' puts the formula into column A starting with row 2 though the number of rows in "wsWithData"
wsFormulas.Range("A2:A" & activeRows). _
    FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(returns(Imported!RC[4],Imported!R[1]C[4]),"""")"

' puts the formula into column C starting with row 2 though the number of rows in "wsWithData"
wsFormulas.Range("C2:C" & activeRows). _
    FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(returns(Imported!RC[10],Imported!R[1]C[10]),"""")"

' ========================================================
' ========================================================
```

End Sub